# Trying to get exact temperature down to 2 decimal places

Tags: c

Hello I am running the TI CC3220SF intro program that shows off the integrated temperature sensor. The communication to this sensor is using I2C which is convenient because i would like to implement a different more accurate sensor using the same protocol. In the provided example by TI they measure the temperature as an int which is preventing precise measurements. I tried type casting the temperature value but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me alleviate this problem?

```
/*
 *  ======== mainThread ========
 */
void *mainThread(void *arg0)

{
  unsigned int    i;
  uint16_t        temperature;
  uint16_t        temperature_f;
  uint8_t         txBuffer[1];
  uint8_t         rxBuffer[2];
  I2C_Handle      i2c;
  I2C_Params      i2cParams;
  I2C_Transaction i2cTransaction;

/* Call driver init functions */
Display_init();
GPIO_init();
I2C_init();

/* Configure the LED pin */
GPIO_setConfig(Board_GPIO_LED0, GPIO_CFG_OUT_STD | GPIO_CFG_OUT_LOW);

/* Open the HOST display for output */
display = Display_open(Display_Type_UART, NULL);
if (display == NULL) {
    while (1);
}

/* Turn on user LED */
GPIO_write(Board_GPIO_LED0, Board_GPIO_LED_ON);
Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Starting the i2ctmp006 example\n");

/* Create I2C for usage */
I2C_Params_init(&i2cParams);
i2cParams.bitRate = I2C_400kHz;
i2c = I2C_open(Board_I2C_TMP, &i2cParams);
if (i2c == NULL) {
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Error Initializing I2C\n");
    while (1);
}
else {
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "I2C Initialized!\n");
}

/* Point to the T ambient register and read its 2 bytes */
txBuffer[0] = TMP006_DIE_TEMP;
i2cTransaction.slaveAddress = Board_TMP_ADDR;
i2cTransaction.writeBuf = txBuffer;
i2cTransaction.writeCount = 1;
i2cTransaction.readBuf = rxBuffer;
i2cTransaction.readCount = 2;

/* Take samples and print them out onto the console */
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (I2C_transfer(i2c, &i2cTransaction)) {
        /* Extract degrees C from the received data; see TMP102 datasheet */
        temperature = (rxBuffer[0] << 6) | (rxBuffer[1] >> 2);

        /*
         * If the MSB is set '1', then we have a 2's complement
         * negative value which needs to be sign extended
         */
        if (rxBuffer[0] & 0x80) {
            temperature |= 0xF000;
        }
       /*
        * For simplicity, divide the temperature value by 32 to get rid of
        * the decimal precision; see TI's TMP006 datasheet
        */
        temperature /= 32;
        temperature_f = ((temperature * 9 / 5) + 32);

        Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Sample %u: %d (C)", i, temperature);
        Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "       %u: %d (F)\n", i, temperature_f);
    }
    else {
        Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "I2C Bus fault\n");
    }

    /* Sleep for x seconds */
    sleep(1);
}

/* Deinitialized I2C */
I2C_close(i2c);
Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "I2C closed!\n");

return (0);
}
```

Comment: Won't the sensor just return an int no matter what, but as single precision?

Comment: Once the information is gone, it's gone. If you have a sensor that can return fractional results, then you need to implement that yourself, or find an implementation for it.

Comment: The code has a comment: *For simplicity, divide the temperature value by 32 to get rid of the decimal precision*. Have you tried not doing that?

Comment: You have not shown where `temperature` is defined for `temperature = (rxBuffer[0] << 6) | (rxBuffer[1] >> 2);` but in a `struct` it is `int`. Then doing `temperature /= 32;` *before* the units conversion will lose significance. But how many sensors are accurate to 2 decimal places anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines do integer math which get rid of the precision

```
temperature /= 32;
temperature_f = ((temperature * 9 / 5) + 32);
```

You would need to define one new variable and change the `temperature_f` type.

```
float ftemperature = 0.0f;
float temperature_f = 0.0f;
...
ftemperature = temperature / 32.0f;
temperature_f = ((ftemperature * 9.0f / 5.0f) + 32.0f);
```

To be more explicit, you can use a cast of the `temperature` like so:

```
ftemperature = ((float) temperature) / 32.0f;
```

However, the `32.0f` is enough to tell the compiler to do that conversion implicitly.

Now you have the precision you want in `ftemperature` and `temperature_f`. You can then use that in the Display functions.

```
Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Sample %u: %f (C)", i, ftemperature);
Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "       %u: %f (F)\n", i, temperature_f);
```

The `%f` format may need a little help. You may want to use `%g` too. See the `printf` docs for details about that.